# Launching Material UI Onepirate: Resolving ENOENT Error on Startup

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js, material-ui, pnpm

When trying to start the 'Material UI Onepirate' template with 'pnpm start', I encounter an error stating that the 'BUILD_ID' file is missing. Even after installing all required pnpm dependencies, the error persists. I have checked the repository and confirmed that the 'BUILD_ID' file is not present. Despite attempting various commands and approaches, I have not been able to resolve the issue.

I attempted to launch the "Material UI Onepirate" template using pnpm start, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\user\Downloads\material-ui-master\material-ui-master\docs> pnpm start

docs@5.0.0 start C:\Users\user\Downloads\material-ui-master\material-ui-master\docs
next start

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\material-ui-master\material-ui-master\docs\export\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\material-ui-master\\material-ui-master\\docs\\export\\BUILD_ID'
}
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I have installed the pnpm dependencies, but I am still encountering the same error. You can find the template's GitHub repository at:
https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/premium-themes/onepirate

Any help or suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code repository you've shared, the project is indeed using Next.js. To start the development server, which allows for hot reloading and a development-friendly environment with additional debugging features, you should use the following command:

```
pnpm run dev
```

This command will start the Next.js development server, typically accessible at http://localhost:3000 by default.
For running the application in production mode, which is optimized for performance and is meant for serving the application to end-users, you need to first build the project. The build process compiles your application and optimizes it for the best performance. You can create a production build using:

```
pnpm run build
```

Once the build is complete and successful, you can start the production server with the following command:

```
pnpm start
```

This command serves the production build of your Next.js application.